# Rust vs Go concurrent webserver, why is Rust slow here?

Tags: concurrency, rust, webserver

I was trying out some benchmarking of the [multi-threaded webserver example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html) in the Rust book and for comparison I built something similar in Go and ran a benchmark using ApacheBench. Though its a simple example the difference was way too much. Go web server doing the same was 10 times faster. Since I was expecting Rust to be faster or at same level, I tried multiple revisions using futures and smol (Though my goal was to compare implementations using only standard library) but result was almost the same. Can anyone here suggest changes to the Rust implementation to make it faster without using a huge thread count?

Here is the code I used: https://github.com/deepu105/concurrency-benchmarks

The tokio-http version is the slowest, the other 3 rust versions give almost same result

Here are the benchmarks:

**Rust (with 8 threads, with 100 threads the numbers are closer to Go):**

```
❯ ab -c 100 -n 1000 http://localhost:8080/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1879490 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        176 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   26.027 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      195000 bytes
HTML transferred:       176000 bytes
Requests per second:    38.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2602.703 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       26.027 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          7.32 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2   2.9      1      16
Processing:     4 2304 1082.5   2001    5996
Waiting:        0 2303 1082.7   2001    5996
Total:          4 2307 1082.1   2002    5997

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   2002
  66%   2008
  75%   2018
  80%   3984
  90%   3997
  95%   4002
  98%   4005
  99%   5983
 100%   5997 (longest request)
```

**Go:**

```
ab -c 100 -n 1000 http://localhost:8080/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1879490 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        174 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   2.102 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      291000 bytes
HTML transferred:       174000 bytes
Requests per second:    475.84 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       210.156 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.102 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          135.22 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2   1.4      2       5
Processing:     0  203 599.8      3    2008
Waiting:        0  202 600.0      2    2008
Total:          0  205 599.8      5    2013

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%      7
  75%      8
  80%      8
  90%   2000
  95%   2003
  98%   2005
  99%   2010
 100%   2013 (longest request)
```

Comment: tokio_minihttp is just a proof of concept and is unmaintained. The Multithreaded Web Server chapter in the book is just an example. The Go standard library has a well revised and optimized http implementation. To get an equal comparison I would try using Hyper or Actix-Web.

Comment: the post is good, but the benchmark is bad. worth to update or to close/delete.

Comment: @mh-cbon what do you mean, could you elaborate plz

Comment: because even though some people will argue ab is not the right tool for the benchmark, at least the post contains clear and reproducible contents. Though becasue the rust version is not as good as it should be, it is missleading. apple and pear comparison. I saw your answer below. this improves that.

Comment: Come on isn't that the point of SO, its a question and not a statement. If the Rust version was as good as it could be I wouldn't have to ask the question right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get similar results in Rust using the async_std lib

```
❯ ab -c 100 -n 1000 http://localhost:8080/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1879490 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        176 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   2.094 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      195000 bytes
HTML transferred:       176000 bytes
Requests per second:    477.47 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       209.439 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.094 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          90.92 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2   1.7      2       7
Processing:     0  202 599.7      2    2002
Waiting:        0  201 600.1      1    2002
Total:          0  205 599.7      5    2007

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%      6
  75%      9
  80%      9
  90%   2000
  95%   2003
  98%   2004
  99%   2006
 100%   2007 (longest request)
```

Here is the implementation

```
use async_std::net::TcpListener;
use async_std::net::TcpStream;
use async_std::prelude::*;
use async_std::task;
use std::fs;
use std::time::Duration;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await.unwrap(); // set listen port

    loop {
        count = count + 1;
        let count_n = Box::new(count);
        let (stream, _) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        task::spawn(handle_connection(stream, count_n)); // spawn a new task to handle the connection
    }
}

async fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream, count: Box<i64>) {
    // Read the first 1024 bytes of data from the stream
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).await.unwrap();

    // add 2 second delay to every 10th request
    if (*count % 10) == 0 {
        println!("Adding delay. Count: {}", count);
        task::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
    }

    let contents = fs::read_to_string("hello.html").unwrap(); // read html file

    let response = format!("{}{}", "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n", contents);
    stream.write(response.as_bytes()).await.unwrap(); // write response
    stream.flush().await.unwrap();
}
```

Comment: and when running 10k requests actually rust async implementation is faster by few seconds overall.

Comment: This rust version should be faster than the Go version because it doesn't really do the same thing. It just accepts TCP connections and writes the file back, it does not represent a real webserver like you have in the Go version. The comparison is not really fair.

Comment: So if I use an HTTP library like hyper in Rust would that be fairer? or you can propose something better for Go?

Comment: I wrote a TCP version in Go to make it fairer. There might be a minor improvement. I will have to run the ab benchmark few time to confirm https://github.com/deepu105/concurrency-benchmarks/blob/main/gows_tcp/main.go

Comment: The http version is faster than pure TCP version by 0.1 second and its still 0.1 s slower than Rust for 10000 request with 100 concurrent request

Comment: The http version might be faster because it caches the read buffers while yours allocates it each time newly. See https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=91602:91648#L835 BTW If you use the -k parameter with the http version you should see some improvement because it can re-use connections.

Comment: Yup that must be the reason, thats why went with HTTP as its the better option provided by Go for this

Answer (score 2):

I only compared your "rustws" and the Go version. In Go you have unlimited goroutines (even though you limit them all to only one CPU core) while in rustws you create a thread pool with 8 threads.

Since your request handlers sleep 2 seconds for every 10th request you are limiting the rustws version to 80/2 = 40 requests per second which is what you are seeing in the ab results. Go does not suffer from this arbitrary bottleneck so it shows you the maximum it candle handle on a single CPU core.

Comment: These are the ways I can think of that can help with the given bottleneck: 1. Async code 2. Threads 3. Processes. You could increase the thread limit to something huge like 1000 and see how it goes. Threads will not be as efficient as goroutines or the async code though.

Comment: True, Actually, based on a comment on Reddit I was able to get same performance from the `rustws_async` sample https://github.com/deepu105/concurrency-benchmarks/blob/main/rustws_async/src/main.rs